# I had made a bot but it sometimes fails to answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

This bot is made for chatting like a human where it uses a endpoint it works good but sometimes.

I tried my best to solve it but it still gives error.

**My unmodified code**

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_response(query):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
        async with ses.get(
            f'https://some-random-api.ml/chatbot?message={query}'
        ) as resp:
            return (await resp.json())['response']
async def main():
    print(await get_response('world'))
```

**But it gives error**

```
rep = await get_response(query)

File "/app/chatbot/plugins/response.py", line 9, in get_response

 return (await resp.json())['response']

KeyError: 'response'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use asycio.gather to gather the task wich will make your code resiliant to spam. `gather` lets you fire off a bunch of coroutines simultaneously, and the current context will resume once all of the coroutines have completed.

**here is how to fix it:**

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def get_response(query):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
        async with ses.get(
            f'https://some-random-api.ml/chatbot?message={query}'
        ) as resp:
            return (await resp.json()),['response']
    
#using an event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Task = asyncio.gather(*[get_response('world') for _ in range(500)])

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(Task)
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225207/discussion-between-reejit-and-terminator).